# I don't understand AJAX callbacks

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a javascript function which executes on the change of a dropdown:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function()
        {
            // Executes when the status dropdown changes value
            $('select[name="status_dropdown"]').change(function(event)
            {
                var $this = $(event.target);
                var orderId = $this.closest('tr').children('td:eq(0)').text(); // index 0 refers to the "order_id column" in the table

                var result = null;
                var scriptUrl = "ajax_php/update_status.php?order_id=" + orderId + "&status_id=" + this.value;

                $.ajax(
                {
                    url: scriptUrl,
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    async: false,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                       result = data;
                       alert(result);
                   }
                });
            });
        })
    </script>
```

I am trying to get the alert call to show the return value of the following php code (which is true):

```
    <?php
        .
        .
        .

        return true;
    ?>
```

The alert doesn't pop up. Anyone know why ???

Comment: check your console for any errors and add an error handler also

Comment: it would seem to me that your problem is that you are using a dataType: html which means that you're ajax request is expecting html data to be returned to it. if invalid html (or something that isn't html) is returned, the success function will never fire because technically it was not successful in receiving what it was expecting. Ajax stands for asynchronous javascript and xml (more commonly Json nowadays) and html is not something you should be sending back and forth this way. ALSO i just noticed asynch set to false.. angels die whenever this flag is set to false. why use ajax then?

Comment: Oh, the async thing was from another post, I now forgot why I added it  :\  I'll remove that, thanks!

So you're saying that I have to return HTML instead of a simple varialbe? I should echo out HTML in the php?

Comment: well yes if your ajax call is expecting html. in your call you set the dataType property to html. you can try removing the property all together and ajax will try to guess using the mime type. This will work most of the time but if you want to be sure you need to set it to a type that you will return from the php. I like to always use json as it keeps things consistent but its a personal preference as you can use xml or another data structure. dataType and the data returned need to be the same type of data structure for success to fire

Comment: So I finally got one part working! The path was wrong as someone has mentioned. I also removed the async:false and removed the dataType: 'html" since I just need to return true or false, or 1/0. I get an alert, but it's empty... I'm almost there... thank you for all the help, I just need to understand why 'data' is empty... –

Comment: DONE!

I simply had to 'echo true' instead of 'return true' in my php code  :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code with another URL and it's working well.
There are three cases:

- scriptUrl is not calculated properly and doesn't point to your PHP script
- your server is down
- you are accessing an URL not served under the same domain as the one of your script (same-origin policy)

You can see detail of your error if you add an error handler to ajax parameters :

```
error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(errorThrown);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Return only returns a value within the php script - to output it to ajax you need to actually output the result to the page, in this case something like `echo "true";` or `print("true");`

Comment: My point is ajax gets the data by reading the contents of the page, not what php returns - therefore you weren't outputting anything to the ajax call.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name="status_dropdown"]').change(function(event)
        {
            var $this = $(event.target);
            var orderId = $this.closest('tr').children('td:eq(0)').text(); // index 0 refers to the "order_id column" in the table

            var result = null;
            var scriptUrl = "ajax_php/update_status.php?order_id=" + orderId + "&status_id=" + this.value;

            $.ajax(
            {
                url: scriptUrl,
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'html',
                async: false,
                success: function(data)
                {
                   result = data;
                   alert(result);
               }
            });
        });
});
```